# How to make my graph stand on the right side like this one?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image: I want to make my graph stand on the right side like this one]

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %Chỉnh dãn dòng
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
{\color{blue}\textbf{Câu 5: }} Cho đồ thị của hàm số $y=x^4-3x^2-3$ như hình dưới. Với giá trị nào của $m$ thì $x^4-3x^2+m=0$ có đúng ba nghiệm phân biệt?\\
\begin{center}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.085554436516331,
xmax=3.1948065326963238,
ymin=-5.445845932334671,
ymax=1.1433852484786022,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-5.0,-4.0,...,1.0},]
\clip(-3.085554436516331,-5.445845932334671) rectangle (3.1948065326963238,1.1433852484786022);
\draw[line width=0.4pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.085554436516331:3.1948065326963238] plot(\x,{(\x)^(4.0)-3.0*(\x)^(2.0)-3.0});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.9530303273140492,4.90988588438619) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
{\color{red}\textbf{A. }} m=0 & {\color{blue}\textbf{B. }} m=4 & {\color{blue}\textbf{C. }} m=-4  & {\color{blue}\textbf{D. }} m=-3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Depending on what document class, packages and environments you are, `wrapfigure` may be your friend. Please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` such that people may answer your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your advise, I'm gonna change it now.

Comment: Thanks! you are missing a `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other commonly used approach is to use a `minipage` and `\raisebox`.  It helps to measure the width first.

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %Chỉnh dãn dòng
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{% measure size
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.085554436516331,
xmax=3.1948065326963238,
ymin=-5.445845932334671,
ymax=1.1433852484786022,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-5.0,-4.0,...,1.0},]
\clip(-3.085554436516331,-5.445845932334671) rectangle (3.1948065326963238,1.1433852484786022);
\draw[line width=0.4pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.085554436516331:3.1948065326963238] plot(\x,{(\x)^(4.0)-3.0*(\x)^(2.0)-3.0});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.9530303273140492,4.90988588438619) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}%
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
{\color{blue}\textbf{Câu 5: }} Cho đồ thị của hàm số $y=x^4-3x^2-3$ như hình dưới. Với giá trị nào của $m$ thì $x^4-3x^2+m=0$ có đúng ba nghiệm phân biệt?\\

\noindent\hfil\begin{tabular}{llrr}
{\color{red}\textbf{A. }} m=0 & {\color{blue}\textbf{B. }} m=4 & {\color{blue}\textbf{C. }} m=-4  & {\color{blue}\textbf{D. }} m=-3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill\raisebox{-\ht0}{\usebox0}

The next line starts here.

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sort of minimal damage answer in which I only made minor changes in the code. I changed `\color` to `\textcolor` and replaced the scriptsize environment in the `tikzpicture` by something more appropriate. (Why do you load pgfplots and start an axis, are you using it?)

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %Chỉnh dãn dòng
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}[0pt]{6cm}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.085554436516331,
xmax=3.1948065326963238,
ymin=-5.445845932334671,
ymax=1.1433852484786022,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-5.0,-4.0,...,1.0},]
\clip(-3.085554436516331,-5.445845932334671) rectangle (3.1948065326963238,1.1433852484786022);
\draw[line width=0.4pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.085554436516331:3.1948065326963238] plot(\x,{(\x)^(4.0)-3.0*(\x)^(2.0)-3.0});
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.9530303273140492,4.90988588438619) node[font=\scriptsize] {$f$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}


\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{Câu 5:}} Cho đồ thị của hàm số $y=x^4-3x^2-3$ như hình dưới. Với giá trị nào của $m$ thì $x^4-3x^2+m=0$ có đúng ba nghiệm phân biệt?\\
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{A. }} m=0 & \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{B. }} m=4 & 
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{C. }} m=-4  & \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{D. }} m=-3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I generated code draw that graph from GeoGebra @@ I'm trying to manage my time on pgfplots. Thank you a lot for your help !!!

Comment: BTW, wrapfig treats a tabular as one line of text (\baselinskip), so will not stop as soon as it should.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Good point! However, in my experience one always has to adjust the number of narrow lines by hand. I would not have used a table to typeset that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you need margin figures often, consider use the `tufte-handout` or the `tufte-book` class:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\begin{document}
\noindent{\color{blue}\textbf{Câu 5: }} Cho đồ thị của hàm số $y=x^4-3x^2-3$ như hình dưới. Với giá trị nào của $m$ thì $x^4-3x^2+m=0$ có đúng ba nghiệm phân biệt?
\begin{marginfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=0.65cm,y=0.65cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.085554436516331,
xmax=3.1948065326963238,
ymin=-5.445845932334671,
ymax=1.1433852484786022,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-5.0,-4.0,...,1.0},]
\clip(-3.085554436516331,-5.445845932334671) rectangle (3.1948065326963238,1.1433852484786022);
\draw[line width=0.4pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.085554436516331:3.1948065326963238] plot(\x,{(\x)^(4.0)-3.0*(\x)^(2.0)-3.0});
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.9530303273140492,4.90988588438619) node {$f$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2em]
\item[\color{red}A.] $\mathrm{m}=0$
\item[\color{blue}B.] $\mathrm{m}=4$ 
\item[\color{blue}C.] $\mathrm{m}=-4$ 
\item[\color{blue}D.] $\mathrm{m}=-3$ 
\begin{itemize}
\end{document}
```